# Coin Flip Code Error/Issue

Tags: java

So.. I'm trying to learn more Java, and decided to create a simple heads / tails coin flip, but can't seem to get it to work. Gives error on "else" with "Syntax error on token "else", { expected", but at the end of the line I already have a {. Can anyone explain this to me? or what I am doing wrong? Thanks

```
import java.util.Random;

class CoinFlip {
    static int flip;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    coin();
    }

    static void coin() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    flip = rand.nextInt(2);
    System.out.println("You flipped a " + flip);
    heads(flip);
    }

    static void heads(int flip) {
    if (flip == 1)
        System.out.println("Heads");
    }

         else if (flip == 2) {
         System.out.println("You win! Congratulations!");
         }  
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answers have indicated you missed an opening brace on your `if`-statement. I'll just add a few other suggestions.

- Consider formatting your code properly by indenting the portions of code within the methods. Doing so will make everything much more readable (and help you find bugs like this!). Some IDEs such as Eclipse have the ability to auto-format the code for you.
- Why not make `flip` a `boolean`? With `true` being heads and `false` being tails. `boolean` is a much more appropriate type for this variable. If you made the change, you could use the [`nextBoolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBoolean%28%29) method of `Random` instead of `nextInt`.

If you made the change mentioned in the second bullet, you could rewrite the `if` as

```
if (flip) {
    System.out.println("Heads");
} else {
    System.out.println("You win! Congratulations!");
}
```

Much clearer in my opinion.

Comment: I will also recommend to always use `{}`. Even its true that one statement allowed just after `if`, `else` and `for`

Answer (score 2):

you missed an **opening brace** for `if statement`

```
 if (flip == 1) {
        System.out.println("Heads");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This line:
`if (flip == 1)`

should be changed to:

`if (flip == 1){`

That should fix it!